# Map without side-effects? A map that takes ownership (and not a mutable reference) on insert?

Tags: rust, ownership

Is there a data structure in Rust that would have the following kind of function signatures?

```rs
impl<K, V> Map<K,V> {
  fn insert(self, key: K, value: V) -> Self
}
```

i.e. It does not take a mutable reference to itself, and instead takes ownership (like a builder pattern).

Inspiration mostly comes from something like a [Haskell Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:insert)

Comment: In Rust you can already write extension trait with an `insert` function with this signature using the standard Map type. Implementing a whole new data structure isn't needed.

Comment: Rust isn't well optimized for this form of immutable data structure. It's best just to use a mutable reference, because the borrow checker prevents the issues that mutable data structures have in other languages. That said, you can just create a newtype wrapping an existing map type such as `std::collection::HashMap`. Mutation is idiomatic in this case, and you'll likely find it to be much more ergonomic.

Comment: @PitaJ This doesn't make the data structure immutable; it just allows chaining like `map.insert(k1, v1).insert(k2, v2)`.

Comment: Immutable data structures (like the Haskell Map type they give as an example) usually work with a signature like theirs. It also makes it chainable, but that could achieved by a function signature like `fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> &mut Self`.

Comment: @PitaJ there are immutable / persistent datastructures and they work fine, they usually need to use Rc or arena but that's essentially what they rely on in higher level language. See `im`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can create a new type that internally uses `std::collections::HashMap`. Here is a basic example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ops::Deref;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Map<K, V>(HashMap<K, V>);

impl<K, V> Deref for Map<K, V> {
    type Target = HashMap<K, V>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<K, V> Map<K, V>
where
    K: std::hash::Hash + Eq,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Map(HashMap::new())
    }

    pub fn insert(mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Self {
        self.0.insert(key, value);

        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let map = Map::new()
        .insert("a", "A")
        .insert("b", "B")
        .insert("c", "C");

    println!("{:?}", map);
    println!("{:?}", *map);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61eb137defe2aceef7e748f52c0037b7

Comment: `Deref` is the magic that makes it an "I can't believe it's not a `HashMap`" when used.